# Does nopCommerce have a log file? If so, in what location is it stored?

Tags: nopcommerce

I have been waiting for nopCommerce to install for about half an hour now (onto a free tier AWS server) and I would love to see if the install is still going on or if it has crashed at some point.

Does nopCommerce output a log file that I could view with a tool like baretail?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, NopCommerce's installation is a pain in the neck. It takes really long and no one knows if it is doing something. However, in my experience with NopCommerce, I have installed it more than 10 times and it has never failed. So, it is just a matter of waiting.

To reply your answer about the log, there is a SQL table "Log" that stores all errors, and also an option from the admin to view a report of this table. It is really good.

However, because NopCommerce is being installed and this table may not yet exist, you can also check the Windows Event log using the event viewer.